# Custom css for border-bottom

Tags: css, border, customization

I had applied css to [this thing](http://puu.sh/l5HOe/e8b7cb72e7.png) but is there any way where i can do css of [this type](http://puu.sh/l5HU6/d900887aaa.png) ?

means decreasing the bottom of the border line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this help.

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 30px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
p:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 80%;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  hello
</p>
```

Comment: you are right this can be done but on hover its not working but will see that and it was really helpful

Comment: use `p:hover:before` to customize the black border.